# Java - "i" cannot be resolved as a variable issue

Tags: java, variables

I am working on this program and I keep getting this error in Java Eclipse saying that "i cannot be resolved to a variable." when I try to get the output..

Here is the relevant code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < animal.length; i++){
    animal[i].move();
    animal[i].makeSound();
    if (animal[i] instanceof Leopard)
        animal[i].findTree();
    if (animal[i] instanceof Bat)
        animal[i].locateInsect();
    if (animal[i] instanceof Chameleon)
        animal[i].changeColor();
}
System.out.println(animal[i].getName());
System.out.println();
```

This is the line that shows the error but I am not sure why its causing an error message.

```
    System.out.println(animal[i].getName());
```

Comment: Can't you just extract piece of code that is small enough to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < animal.length; i++){
    //...
}
System.out.println(animal[i].getName());
```

You're trying to reference the `i` outside of the forloop where you created it, so it doesn't exist.

Simply move `System.out.println(animal[i].getName());` inside of the forloop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < animal.length; i++){
    //...
    System.out.println(animal[i].getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understands the basics of java variable scope

http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: Instead of just telling OP what he needs to understand and posting a link, you should actually explain it here. What you've posted is not an answer, it is a comment.

Comment: The link explains the root cause of the problem he is having. I don't believe it's a comment, it's just your opinion.

Comment: The link explains the root cause, not you. If you want to post an answer, do so by explaining the answer here. That link may die in the future and would therefor render your "answer" useless. That is why link only answers are discouraged on this site.